# Evaluating a maximum likelihood expression using datamasks in R

Tags: r, eval, tidyeval

I am trying to evaluate a maximum likelihood expression using data masks. The idea is to allow parameters and variables to be called by name within the function while avoiding multiple calls to `attach()` and `detach()`. This is a small very simplified example and the real functions are quite large and complex.

```
set.seed(1)

# Data
db <- data.frame(
  x = runif(10),
  y = runif(10),
  z = sample(c(0, 1), 10, replace = TRUE)
)

# Log likelihood function
ll_lik <- function(param) {
  pr_1 <- 1 / (1 + exp(-(param[1]*x - param[2]*y)))
  pr_2 <- 1 - pr_1
  lik <- z * pr_1 + (1 - z) * pr_2
  log(lik)
}

# Parameters
param <- c(p1 = 0.1, p2 = 0.2)

# Run the model with attach()/detach()
attach(db)
model <- maxLik::maxLik(ll_lik, start = param)
detach(db)
summary(model)
```

This works fine, however, I have to make calls to `attach()` and `detach()`. To access the parameters by name, I would need to transform the `param` to a list inside the log-likelihood function and then make calls to `attach()`/`detach()`. Not only is this messy, but with large functions and data, it creates unneccessary overhead. One possibility that I have been looking at is to use the `rlang` package and the wrapper functions mostly written for tidy evaluation of expressions.

Now, just creating the datamask and trying to evaluate the log-likelihood function does not work:

```
mask <- as_data_mask(db)
eval_tidy(quo(maxLik::maxLik(ll_lik, start = param)), mask)
```

It cannot access the objects in the datamask (`Error in fnOrig(theta, ...) : object 'x' not found`). Maybe the issue was with `maxLik`, but I couldn't even evaluate `ll_lik()` and this gave the same error:

```
eval_tidy(quo(ll_lik(param)), mask)
```

But this works:

```
eval_tidy(quo(x*3), mask)
```

So, I began to suspect that `ll_lik()` has the "wrong" parent, which is why my datamask might not be in the search path for the function, hence it cannot find the variables. Now, the help section for `as_data_mask()` does provide some examples of how to "nest" environments by creating top, middle and bottom level environments. Ok, so let's see if I can create my function as part of the data mask structure:

```
call_stack <- function() {lobstr::cst()}

# Create a new environment (child of empty) that takes a list of objects to populate it
top <- new_environment(list(ll_lik = ll_lik, call_stack = call_stack))

# Create a child of the "top" environment"
middle <- env(top)

# Create a child of the "middle environment and add the data object to it
bottom <- env(middle, db=db)

# Create a data_mask where the bottom contains the masking elements and the top
# the last element of the data_mask.
new_mask <- new_data_mask(bottom, top = top)
```

Unfortunately, I am still unable to access `x`. I didn't even attemtp the `maxLik` function here. So to try and dig deeper, I started messing around with the call stack.

```
eval_tidy(call_stack(), data = new_mask)
```

And indeed, if I read this correctly, the parent of the function is the global environment.

```
    █
 1. ├─rlang::eval_tidy(call_stack(), data = new_mask)
 2. └─global::call_stack()
 3.   └─lobstr::cst()
```

I am, however, at a loss for how to make this work. Any help is much appreciated.

BONOUS: If I am able to call the parameters by name inside `maxLik` without calls to `attach()`/`detach()`, that would be awesome.

Comment: Hi! I'm not an expert on `datamasks`, so I cannot comment on how to access the objects in `db` using that approach, but I was just wondering a (maybe stupid) question. I read on the help page of the `maxLik` function the following sentence: "... : [...] Arguments not used by the optimizers are forwarded to `logLik`, `grad` and `hess`". I think that you can define `ll_lik` function with parameters `x`, `y` and `z` and then pass the corresponding values using `db$x` or using `with` function. If you want I can provide a more detailed answer with this approach.

Comment: Yeah, the use of `attach()` is to avoid having to put `db$` in front of all the variables (there are quite a few in some cases). I think I have tried using the `with()` function before running into similar problems. If I understand `with()` correctly, it does function similar to a datamask, but the datamask can contain data, functions and other objects you may want to access inside the log likelihood function. I may also have misunderstood this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a wrapper that evaluates the body of `ll_lik` as an expression, with `db` as the context:

```
llwrap <- function(param) {
  eval( body(ll_lik), db )
}

model <- maxLik::maxLik(llwrap, start=param)      # Works
```

**EDIT** to address your question: yes, `body()` returns an expression, so you can use whatever names you want inside that expression, as long as you provide the appropriate context at evaluation. However, if you are completely decoupling the body of your function from its argument list, why not just define it as an expression from the beginning?

```
ll_expr <- rlang::expr({                       # An expression, not a function
  pr_1 <- 1 / (1 + exp(-(p1*x - p2*y)))        # <-- now using p1, p2
  pr_2 <- 1 - pr_1
  lik <- z * pr_1 + (1 - z) * pr_2
  log(lik)
})

llwrap2 <- function(param) {
  ctx <- c( as.list(db), as.list(param) )      # Combine param and db into one context
  eval( ll_expr, ctx )                         # No longer need body()
}

model <- maxLik::maxLik(llwrap2, start=param)  # Works
```

Comment: Interesting. I was unaware of `body()`. Would this approach also be extendable to allow the elements of `param` to be called by name as well, as opposed to `param[1]`, `param[2]` etc.?

Comment: Thank you very much for the updated answer. It is definitely a step in the right direction. I will play around with your solution a little in the context of the bigger code to see how it behaves. Cheers.

Comment: I'm intrigued by this question and answer, what is the wider use of what you are doing or is it primarily when you are working on stuff stored in a dataframe? I like the idea of not creating an environment, would you have a link to any other similar questions to get a wider understanding? thanks

Comment: @user63230: Technically, it *is* creating an environment. `eval()` will convert the list supplied as the second argument to an environment, in which the first argument (the expression) will be evaluated. The eval pattern in this answer is basically just a sophisticated `with()`. Consider `with( mtcars, mpg*cyl )`. By storing the expression in a variable `e <- rlang::expr(mpg*cyl)`, we can delay its evaluation until `mtcars` is ready: `eval( e, mtcars )`. That's really all that's happening here. Data frames is the most canonical case, but anything with variable masking is fair game.

Comment: thanks, so its just for variable masking, similar to `mutate` so.... What I meant about creating an environment was you don't have to explicitly create one e.g. `envr <- new.env()` and then fill it!

Comment: @user63230 In the context of expression evaluation, you can think of lists, data frames and environments as being interchangeable. So, yes, it's true: we are not explicitly calling `new.env()`. However, we *are* explicitly creating a list with `c( as.list(db), as.list(param) )`, which then implicitly gets converted to an environment by `eval()`.